# How can I program my DApp to tell my user that their action/transaction has been confirmed?

Tags: dapp-development, web3js, events, library, confirmations

Take an example of a voting DApp.  A user clicks on a vote button, then behind the scenes the transaction containing the vote gets mined on the blockchain.  The DApp then wants to `alert('You have voted')`.

Since the transaction takes some time to get mined and get some confirmations, what code should the DApp do before it does the `alert`?  I have heard of people running loops and calling `getTransactionReceipt`.  Is this how it should be done, or alternatives?  Are there any code snippets or libraries for them?

Answer (score 1):

In web3.js, `.sendTransaction()` has a callback.

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction

More about the callback: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#using-callbacks

The callback is typically called twice, once when the transaction hits the network, and again once it has been mined.

Also, using `alert()` is generally discouraged from javascript as it is a blocking call and goes against the asynchronous nature of javascript. (Better would be to use a Bootstrap popup for instance.)

Comment: `alert` is just for example purpose ;)  Upvoting but code snippets would be more helpful for readers.  Also, "callback is typically called twice"? Snippet for detecting both cases would be helpful.

Comment: I too would like to know how to call the right one at the right time.

Comment: "The callback is typically called twice" is inaccurate.  `.sendTransaction()` only calls the callback once (the callback for `.new` is what is called twice).  http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7407/when-is-a-transaction-callback-called

Answer (score 1):

I have made available a complete working code example here to tell if your transaction has been mined:

[How do I know when I've run out of gas](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/how-do-i-know-when-ive-run-out-of-gas)

(It also accounts for if you run out of gas :-)

Note that if the node you are talking to is untrustworthy this isn't 100% reliable.   How do you know it's not lying? You should really check to make sure the transaction was mined on a sample of nodes.  AFAICT I have yet to see example code of this in the Ethereum world.  There are such examples in bitcoin.   I plan on implementing such code when I go to production (aka using real money)