# How can I use msg.value twice?

Tags: solidity, out-of-gas

I try to deploy the following code:

```
contract Sample {
```

```
struct Participant {
    address etherAddress;
    uint amount;
}

Participant[] public participants;
uint public amountRaised;

function() {
    enter();
}

function enter() {
    uint amount = msg.value;
    uint n = participants.length;

    participants.length += 1;
    participants[n].etherAddress = msg.sender;
    participants[n].amount = amount;

    amountRaised += amount;
}
```

}

In Mix IDE it works correctly but does not work on Ethereum testnet(balance not changed). 
You can try here: http://testnet.etherscan.io/address/0xea1410a6d5ef3d6d5a392b24087c24845e7170a3 .
I noticed that contract works if delete participants[n].amount = amount OR amountRaised += amount line.
So, I can use only one msg.value variable.
How can I use msg.value twice?

Comment: You should be able to use it as many times as you'd like. Have you tried sending more gas? That could be the issue.

Comment: Ok, contract works with bigger gas. Thank you for help! :)

Comment: No problem. That's usually the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often, when removing a few lines solves an issue, it indicates an out-of-gas error.

To diagnose this problem, you can use a block explorer that shows EVM traces, like http://live.ether.camp, or start geth with --debug and watch the logs.

You can also use `msg.gas` to check the remaining gas from within the contract, and throw an event or some other error if it gets too low.

Comment: see also http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/how-do-i-know-when-ive-run-out-of-gas/1182#1182