# How can the transaction status from a thrown error be detected when gas can be exactly the same as the gasUsed for a successful transaction?

Tags: transactions, gas

This question arose from answering [Transaction Status](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6002/transaction-status).

In the following example, I am sending gas of 21,000 (the amount required for a regular transaction). In this situation `gas == gasUsed`, and so cannot be used to determine if the contract has thrown an exception?

```
> eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], to: eth.accounts[1], value: web3.toWei(1.2345, "ether"), gas: 21000})
"0xc7c63b67747c0c825229ce3d36d226423adb8cab6bebe12b6d5001e0dc3f79b3"
> eth.getTransaction("0xc7c63b67747c0c825229ce3d36d226423adb8cab6bebe12b6d5001e0dc3f79b3")
{
  blockHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  blockNumber: null,
  from: "0xa7857047907d53a2e494d5f311b4b586dc6a96d2",
  gas: 21000,
  gasPrice: 20000000000,
  hash: "0xc7c63b67747c0c825229ce3d36d226423adb8cab6bebe12b6d5001e0dc3f79b3",
  input: "0x",
  nonce: 55,
  to: "0x4d5bbe7fbc80933ffa90ece988a764e41ee6d018",
  transactionIndex: null,
  value: 1234500000000000000
}
> eth.getTransactionReceipt("0xc7c63b67747c0c825229ce3d36d226423adb8cab6bebe12b6d5001e0dc3f79b3")
{
  blockHash: "0xf0af8236ceec7ad1839d67c9934ab062a8d95fa1f88b06139f97dbdfbd1cd842",
  blockNumber: 2234,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 21000,
  from: "0xa7857047907d53a2e494d5f311b4b586dc6a96d2",
  gasUsed: 21000,
  logs: [],
  root: "3280f47a0de1149ad5c5fda421faaf95f303da8a77e83c8ec6ac2b3d8ca27abc",
  to: "0x4d5bbe7fbc80933ffa90ece988a764e41ee6d018",
  transactionHash: "0xc7c63b67747c0c825229ce3d36d226423adb8cab6bebe12b6d5001e0dc3f79b3",
  transactionIndex: 0
}
```

A transaction can be set with the gas being exactly the same as the gas that will be used, using [web3.eth.estimateGas](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethestimategas) function to firstly estimate the required gas.

So, how can the transaction status from a thrown error be detected when gas can be exactly the same as the gasUsed for a successful transaction?

---

**EDIT 15/06/2016 - Explaining differences from [How do I know when I've run out of gas programmatically?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/how-do-i-know-when-ive-run-out-of-gas-programmatically)**

In this question, we already KNOW how to detect that we have run out of gas programmatically. And we already know that this method to detect an error transaction is not reliable, as `gas == gasUsed` is a valid condition for a non-error transaction.

What this question is asking is what reliable alternatives are there to detect an error transaction when the "run out of gas" situation is not reliable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I know when I've run out of gas programmatically?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/how-do-i-know-when-ive-run-out-of-gas-programmatically)

Comment: Not a duplicate in my point of view - see EDIT 15/06/2016 above.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Summary

I have sent a test transaction (#1) to firstly find out how much gas a successful smart contract transaction uses. From the results of this transaction, the gas required for a successful transaction is 26747.

I then used this 26747 gas amount in my going-to-be-successful transaction (#2). And `gasUsed == gas`.

I then use this same 26747 gas amount in my going-to-be-UNSUCCESSFUL transaction (#3). And `gasUsed == gas`.

The only reliable way I have found so far to easily check if a smart contract transaction is successful is to use `debug.traceTransaction` and check the last error message. If this is `""` then no error occurred. If this is `"Out of gas"` or `"invalid jump destination (PUSH1) 2"`, then an error occurred.

And here's a short bit of code to determine the status of your transaction.

```
> var status = debug.traceTransaction("0xd23219e2ea10528b245deb9e47993cae2ffd3ffe9fc27aeb808e94fc4e75d37b")
undefined
> if (status.structLogs.length > 0) {
  console.log(status.structLogs[status.structLogs.length-1].error)
}
"invalid jump destination (PUSH1) 2"
```

The return value above will be `""` if there are no errors, or `"Out of gas"` if you run out of gas.

**UPDATE 29/07/2016 - the `geth --fast` blockchain download does not contain the information for `debug.traceTransaction(...)` to display.**

---

## Details

I'm using the following example for a smart contract that throws an exception if _value < 12345:

```
contract TestStatus {
    uint public value;
    function setValue(uint256 _value) {
        value = _value;
        if (_value < 12345) {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

I flattened the source to:

```
var testStatusSource='contract TestStatus { uint public value; function setValue(uint256 _value) { value = _value; if (_value < 12345) { throw; } }}'
```

I compiled and inserted the contract into the blockchain:

```
var testStatusCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(testStatusSource);

var testStatusContract = web3.eth.contract(testStatusCompiled.TestStatus.info.abiDefinition);
var testStatus = testStatusContract.new({
  from:web3.eth.accounts[0], 
  data: testStatusCompiled.TestStatus.code, gas: 1000000}, 
  function(e, contract) {
    if (!e) {
      if (!contract.address) {
        console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + contract.transactionHash + 
          " waiting to be mined...");
      } else {
        console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
        console.log(contract);
      }
  }
})
Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: 0x4de11cc54484333036f45a2441563d6badae43d2e2789e0b113b6703a582a879 waiting to be mined...
undefined
...
Contract mined! Address: 0x87847eb0f944fbb6d5c5a4891e3b103a63cee45c
[object Object]
```

I sent a transaction that won't cause an error to determine the gas required:

```
# Not an error
testStatus.setValue(123456, eth.accounts[0], {
  from:web3.eth.accounts[0], 
  data: testStatusCompiled.TestStatus.code,
  gas: 41747
});
...
> eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x727cb3c6846bbb05c8437e97aa32db39a252426b09ed837a76bb364748ce73c4")
{
  blockHash: "0x293b4d357d72615c409ba37a6430253d64b4646e0366ac987d1364a258cf81fa",
  blockNumber: 2465,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 26747,
  from: "0xa7857047907d53a2e494d5f311b4b586dc6a96d2",
  gasUsed: 26747,
  logs: [],
  root: "fbb29f9eff2340aa8d7df7feec74671c2b693fb9e7b6ec3b710ca6d64813da0e",
  to: "0x87847eb0f944fbb6d5c5a4891e3b103a63cee45c",
  transactionHash: "0x727cb3c6846bbb05c8437e97aa32db39a252426b09ed837a76bb364748ce73c4",
  transactionIndex: 0
}
```

The gas required is 26747.

I sent a transaction with `value=123456` that will NOT fail, and `gas==gasUsed`:

```
testStatus.setValue(123456, eth.accounts[0], {
  from:web3.eth.accounts[0], 
  data: testStatusCompiled.TestStatus.code,
  gas: 26747
});
0xc0ab94adfe473811d055f98528a625dbebf66026b7ec5ad8eab939de862bc2d1
```

I'm using `debug.traceTransaction` to confirm that this transaction has not encountered an error.

```
> var status = debug.traceTransaction("0xc0ab94adfe473811d055f98528a625dbebf66026b7ec5ad8eab939de862bc2d1")
undefined
> status.structLogs[status.structLogs.length-1].error
""
```

And in this situation `gas(26747) == gasUsed(26747)`

```
eth.getTransaction("0xc0ab94adfe473811d055f98528a625dbebf66026b7ec5ad8eab939de862bc2d1")
{
  blockHash: "0x961277e2bebfe8332a23d240672b2658eced493b70fd145c99991c3c8651adcc",
  blockNumber: 2475,
  from: "0xa7857047907d53a2e494d5f311b4b586dc6a96d2",
  gas: 26747,
  gasPrice: 20000000000,
  hash: "0xc0ab94adfe473811d055f98528a625dbebf66026b7ec5ad8eab939de862bc2d1",
  input: "0x55241077000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001e240",
  nonce: 66,
  to: "0x87847eb0f944fbb6d5c5a4891e3b103a63cee45c",
  transactionIndex: 0,
  value: 0
}
eth.getTransactionReceipt("0xc0ab94adfe473811d055f98528a625dbebf66026b7ec5ad8eab939de862bc2d1")
{
  blockHash: "0x961277e2bebfe8332a23d240672b2658eced493b70fd145c99991c3c8651adcc",
  blockNumber: 2475,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 26747,
  from: "0xa7857047907d53a2e494d5f311b4b586dc6a96d2",
  gasUsed: 26747,
  logs: [],
  root: "f850e1e5c99352f47e3409e4e9f966a49c13152e63aaa7bb3765f0b37bfe09e5",
  to: "0x87847eb0f944fbb6d5c5a4891e3b103a63cee45c",
  transactionHash: "0xc0ab94adfe473811d055f98528a625dbebf66026b7ec5ad8eab939de862bc2d1",
  transactionIndex: 0
}
```

I then sent a transaction with `value=123` that failed, and `gas==gasUsed`:

```
testStatus.setValue(123, eth.accounts[0], {
  from:web3.eth.accounts[0], 
  data: testStatusCompiled.TestStatus.code,
  gas: 26747
});

0x9ee86a200528de32a695f1e2dd0d94a3871fefc7e49c5fd24a4a37eab1b99f7a
> var status = debug.traceTransaction("0x9ee86a200528de32a695f1e2dd0d94a3871fefc7e49c5fd24a4a37eab1b99f7a")
undefined
> status.structLogs[status.structLogs.length-1].error
"invalid jump destination (PUSH1) 2"

> eth.getTransaction("0x9ee86a200528de32a695f1e2dd0d94a3871fefc7e49c5fd24a4a37eab1b99f7a")
{
  blockHash: "0x22fb5fcaef27dd017efcde8c3f78df7f5168c505210f5d08872a9c2877146044",
  blockNumber: 2484,
  from: "0xa7857047907d53a2e494d5f311b4b586dc6a96d2",
  gas: 26747,
  gasPrice: 20000000000,
  hash: "0x9ee86a200528de32a695f1e2dd0d94a3871fefc7e49c5fd24a4a37eab1b99f7a",
  input: "0x55241077000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007b",
  nonce: 67,
  to: "0x87847eb0f944fbb6d5c5a4891e3b103a63cee45c",
  transactionIndex: 0,
  value: 0
}
> eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x9ee86a200528de32a695f1e2dd0d94a3871fefc7e49c5fd24a4a37eab1b99f7a")
{
  blockHash: "0x22fb5fcaef27dd017efcde8c3f78df7f5168c505210f5d08872a9c2877146044",
  blockNumber: 2484,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 26747,
  from: "0xa7857047907d53a2e494d5f311b4b586dc6a96d2",
  gasUsed: 26747,
  logs: [],
  root: "ab51ab81c19eb8da7f8d0216d6c2f1d8946e88842b758ff0af13c28ff7e181b4",
  to: "0x87847eb0f944fbb6d5c5a4891e3b103a63cee45c",
  transactionHash: "0x9ee86a200528de32a695f1e2dd0d94a3871fefc7e49c5fd24a4a37eab1b99f7a",
  transactionIndex: 0
}
```

So the only easy reliable way I've found to determine if a smart contract transaction has succeeded or failed is to use `debug.traceTransaction`.

Here's the output of `debug.traceTransaction` for the last transaction that failed.

```
debug.traceTransaction("0x9ee86a200528de32a695f1e2dd0d94a3871fefc7e49c5fd24a4a37eab1b99f7a")
{
  gas: 26747,
  returnValue: "",
  structLogs: [{
      depth: 1,
      error: "",
      gas: 5280,
      gasCost: 3,
      memory: null,
      op: "PUSH1",
      pc: 0,
      stack: [],
      storage: {}
  }, {
      depth: 1,
      error: "",
      gas: 5277,
      gasCost: 3,
      memory: null,
      op: "PUSH1",
      pc: 2,
      stack: ["0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060"],
      storage: {}
  }, {
  ...
  }, {
      depth: 1,
      error: "invalid jump destination (PUSH1) 2",
      gas: 129,
      gasCost: 8,
      memory: ["0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060"],
      op: "JUMP",
      pc: 66,
      stack: ["0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000055241077", "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000022", "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007b"],
      storage: {
        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000: "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007b"
      }
  }]
}
```

And here's a short script to check if the transaction passed or failed:

```
> var status = debug.traceTransaction("0x9ee86a200528de32a695f1e2dd0d94a3871fefc7e49c5fd24a4a37eab1b99f7a")
undefined
> status.structLogs[status.structLogs.length-1].error
"invalid jump destination (PUSH1) 2"
```

Comment: Upvoted, nice, easy use of Geth's `debug.traceTransaction`.

Comment: Overall, if( (eth.getTransactionReceipt($transaction_id) != null) && (status.structLogs.length == 0) ) , then could I conclude that the transaction is passed?

Comment: For a transaction to a contract, the contract vm instructions will execute and the steps are shown in the status.structLogs, so status.structLogs.length will always be > 0. For a transaction to another non-contract account, status.structLogs.length will be 0.

Comment: Good solution but for production environment can we really activate the debug. what will be the overhead?. If the local node is not the mining node, do we get the traceTransaction return something?

Comment: The overhead is that you cannot retrieve the `debug.traceTransaction(...)` information from the portion of the blockchain that is fast synced - the overhead is disk space and the time to sync.

Comment: My debug.traceTransaction(<transactionID>) returns a empty structLogs: []. What might be the reason? @BokkyPooBah

Comment: Your node should be synced with the full archive node option. Test with a recent transaction and if it works, but an older transaction does not work, the issue is that your node has been fast synced.

Comment: `status.structLogs[status.structLogs.length-1].error` returns: `"{}"`. Could I conclude that the transaction passed?  @BokkyPooBah

Comment: The results from `debug.traceTransaction` may have changed. Here is a tx with an error during the TokenCard ICO. `var status = debug.traceTransaction("0xe686a5fd36ec7921c847b9285c9ea09724bc6065c7374462a448f0d384adad82");`. `status.structLogs[status.structLogs.length-1].error` returns `{}`. But `status.structLogs[status.structLogs.length-1].op` returns `"Missing opcode 0xfd"`

Comment: Yes debug.traceTransaction has been updated. So as a result if `status.structLogs[status.structLogs.length-1].op returns` => `"Missing opcode 0xfd"` could I conclude that transaction is throw? I just want to have an identifier to verify that transaction is throw. @BokkyPooBah

Comment: @Avatar - see https://github.com/bokkypoobah/TokenCardICOAnalysis#transaction-status

Comment: What if: `op:JUMP and error: {}` .. does it mean also transaction throw? @BokkyPooBah

Comment: `op:RETURN and error: null ` is a valid transaction? @BokkyPooBah

Comment: don't know if something changed in geth but today with tx `0x6c929e1c3d860ee225d7f3a7addf9e3f740603d243260536dfa2f3cf02b51de4` in debug_traceTransaction `json_resp["result"]["structLogs"]["failed"] == True` contrary to your post `json_resp["result"]["structLogs"][struct_logs_length-1]["error"]` is equal to {}

Answer (score 11):

#### Since block 4370000 (Byzantium), a [`status` indicator](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6144/why-doesnt-the-ethereum-protocol-have-an-indicator-for-a-transaction-that-faile) has been added to receipts.

`eth.getTransactionReceipt(transactionHash)` will return a `status` field that has a value of `0` when a transaction has failed and `1` when the transaction has succeeded.

#### Before block 4370000

The receipt status is null, and to ascertain Out of Gas, the transaction must be processed through the EVM, [which is what some block explorers do](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1179/42).

Out of Gas cannot be detected statically (without executing the transaction), in the general case, due to implications of the [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Even in the case of the simplest transaction that has and uses exactly 21,000 gas, the transaction needs to be executed because the [recipient could reject the Ether](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1477/how-does-rejecting-ether-work-on-contracts-fallback-functions) being sent to it by using a fallback function.  Generally, the code in a fallback function needs to run to determine if it avoids an Out of Gas exception.

`gas == gasUsed` is a good practical heuristic for Out of Gas, given that it's safer to supply a reasonable amount of gas more than `web3.eth.estimateGas` since unused gas is refunded.

Comment: I don't think the halting problem applies here; the transaction's already been executed by the network; it could indicate the reason for halting if the protocol had a provision for that.

Comment: Agree, I asked http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6144/why-doesnt-the-ethereum-protocol-have-an-indicator-for-a-transaction-that-ran-o

Answer (score 4):

Here is my Python code to check this using [Populus](http://populus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [web3.py](https://github.com/pipermerriam/web3.py/):

```
from web3 import Web3
from populus.utils.transactions import wait_for_transaction_receipt

class TransactionConfirmationError(Exception):
    """A transaction was not correctly included in blockchain."""


def confirm_transaction(web3: Web3, txid: str, timeout=60) -> dict:
    """Make sure a transaction was correctly performed.

    Confirm that

    * The transaction has been mined in blockchain

    * The transaction did not throw an error (used up all its gas)

    http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/6007/620

    :raise TransactionConfirmationError: If we did not get it confirmed in time
    :return: Transaction receipt
    """

    try:
        receipt = wait_for_transaction_receipt(web3, txid, timeout)
    except Timeout as e:
        raise TransactionConfirmationError("Could not confirm tx {} within timeout {}".format(txid, timeout)) from e

    tx = web3.eth.getTransaction(txid)

    if tx["gas"] == receipt["gasUsed"]:
        raise TransactionConfirmationError("Transaction failed (out of gas, thrown): {}".format(txid))

    return receipt
```

Comment: Why don't you add the `debug.traceTransaction(...)` check to your code - you will then get the exact error, and you can also detect non-error conditions where gas==gasUsed ?

Comment: Ok. Will update the answer to the get the exact error.

Answer (score 4):

Personally I have been using a different workaround than the traceTransaction method.
It simply consists of having an event log (say Completed()) called at the end of the transactions (contract function).
The process is then:

- Send the transaction and get the TxHash
- Start a setTimeout(maxtoWait, callback)
- Register to "Completed()" on that contract address from currentBlock to currentBlock+5 (or more), with callback
- In callback,

  - if called by timeout (no args) then tx failed (or assumed so!)
  - check if log.transactionHash correspond to your tx
  - if yes then the transaction succeded
  - if no, check if log.blockNumber >= initialBlock+5, then transaction failed.

It is more complex but it does not use traceTransaction which I consider being a debugging function rather than a made for production environment.

Comment: This is a good way to do it if you have access to the source code of the smart contract before its deployed. In my work, doing forensic account (i.e. accounting after the fact), your method is not possible. But, as I say, it's a nice way to do it if you have control of the source.