# Token transfer: Intrinsic gas too low

Tags: mist, gas, ethereum-wallet-dapp, tokens, out-of-gas

I have created a cryptocurrency by following this [link](https://www.ethereum.org/token) .I have deployed the contract in Mist. I am using transferFrom() function in Ethereum wallet to transfer currency from one account to other but getting intrinsic gas too low error(Execution failed. Consumed all provided gas). Although my primaryAccount(from which I am trying to transfer) contains sufficient ethers(more than 20,000 ethers).

```
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        if (balanceOf[_from]  allowance[_from][msg.sender]) throw;   // Check allowance
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                          // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to the recipient
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        reward=calculateReward(now);
        balanceOf[block.coinbase] += reward;
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }
```

while other similar functions such as transfer() are working well.Can't understand why two functions behaving differently. I am  adding the image of error for refrence.

[image]

Comment: `transferFrom` requires more gas than `transfer`.  Did you try increasing the gas?

Comment: I am using Ethereum Wallet, which sets the gas on most commonly used value and I didn't find any way way of increasing the gas from UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I got the answer. There is no issue of low gas in Mist. The function didn't execute because while calling `approveAndCall` we are using `allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;`  but in `transferFrom()` function we are checking value against  `allowance[_from][msg.sender])`.
I modified it to `if (_value > allowance[msg.sender][_from]) throw;` in `transferFrom` and everything started working fine.

Comment: Say you have accounts A and B. A has the tokens. From account A, you `transfer(B, 10)`. Or from account A, you `approveAndCall(B, 10, xxx)` and then from account B, you `transferFrom(A, B, 10)`. If you are using account A to execute all the functions, you would have to make the logic change that you did, but that would negate the purpose of allowing account B to call `transferFrom(...)`.

Comment: I was executing all functions from account A. and I used `transferFrom(B,C,10)` to transfer amount approved by `approveAndCall(B,10,xxx)`. So basically B can transfer to any other account like C, the amount that was approved by A.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that your issue is because you have not approved the transfer required to call `transferFrom(...)`.

Here are the relevant functions:

```
    /* Send coins */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {
        if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value) throw;           // Check if the sender has enough
        if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw; // Check for overflows
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;                     // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to the recipient
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);                   // Notify anyone listening that this transfer took place
    }

    /* Allow another contract to spend some tokens in your behalf */
    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData)
        returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
        spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
        return true;
    }

    /* A contract attempts to get the coins */
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        if (balanceOf[_from] < _value) throw;                 // Check if the sender has enough
        if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw;  // Check for overflows
        if (_value > allowance[_from][msg.sender]) throw;   // Check allowance
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                          // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to the recipient
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }
```

If you are the current owner of the tokens, you can call `transfer(...)` to transfer your balance to another address.

However if you want to transfer from another address, you will need to call `transferFrom(...)` which will check the `allowance[...][...]` data structure to confirm whether this transfer has been approved.

So, call `approveAndCall(...)` first to approve your transfer and you should be able to call `transferFrom(...)` to transfer your tokens.

When you call `transferFrom(...)` without first calling `approveAndCall(...)`, and error is thrown in the line

```
if (_value > allowance[_from][msg.sender]) throw;   // Check allowance
```

This error will appear as an Out Of Gas error in the Ethereum Wallet.

If you are comfortable using `geth`, see [How can the transaction status from a thrown error be detected when gas can be exactly the same as the gasUsed for a successful transaction?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6007/how-can-the-transaction-status-from-a-thrown-error-be-detected-when-gas-can-be-e) for the following code that can be used to check the exact reason for your error:

```
> var status = debug.traceTransaction("0xd23219e2ea10528b245deb9e47993cae2ffd3ffe9fc27aeb808e94fc4e75d37b")
undefined
> if (status.structLogs.length > 0) {
  console.log(status.structLogs[status.structLogs.length-1].error)
}
"invalid jump destination (PUSH1) 2"
```

Comment: I have all these functions in my contract. Also I tried first calling 'approveAndCall(..)' but still getting same error. I know it's related to gas but there are some functions like 'mintTokens(..)' which work fine within a contract and give same error(Intrinsic gas too low)  in other contracts. Note:I am using same accounts for transaction in both contracts in both cases ether account is possessing is same.

Comment: I tried to call `transferFrom()` without calling `approveAndCall()` so that I can understand working of `debug.traceTransaction()`. But when I executed `debug.traceTransaction` I got following error. `var status=debug.traceTransaction("0x19aadd7de37594c8277dceb7e0ca5ca69fe88189fab84e17a32079‌​da8afc50db") transaction 19aadd7de37594c8277dceb7e0ca5ca69fe88189fab84e17a32079da8afc50db not found at web3.js:3119:20 at web3.js:6023:15  at web3.js:4995:36  at <anonymous>:1:13 `

Comment: Which chain are you on? Mainnet, Testnet (Morden) or private? Generate a transaction and then try the `debug.traceTransaction(...)` with the resulting transaction hash.

Comment: I am on private net. I complied `transferFrom(..)` without calling `approveAndCall(...)` in geth console, which returned me a tx hash. I passed it to `debug.traceTransaction(..)` but got error that transaction not found. I know my transfer should have not been done but I was expecting `invalid jump destination (PUSH1) 2`

Comment: Do `eth.getTransaction(txHash)` and `eth.getTransactionReceipt(txHash)` work? If it does, `debug.traceTransaction(txHash)` should work. If it does not, there is something else happening. Check whether you are mining.

Comment: yes they were working. I tried again and all worked fine. Thanks