# Why my contract silently fails on "throw" or out of gas exception?

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity

When I run method that throws or runs out of gas I get nothing in error variable in callback. Method acts like everything's ok, but no changes are made.

For example I call:

```
Test.methodThatThrows({gas: 4752390,from: web3.eth.coinbase}, function(err, res) {console.log(err, res)});
```

I get output like

`null 0x6d5a561224940daa70d6d56c60909255b86af7b9e93a0d8a4f98cacddf0d722b`

This is very confusing, especially when you silently run out of has and don't know what's wrong.

I don't know if it's some compiler or geth option or something, couldn't find out.

I'm using

`geth 1.4.12-stable-421df866
solc Version: 0.4.1+commit.4fc6fc2.Darwin.appleclang or
0.4.3-develop.2016.9.22+commit.c06ba011.Darwin.appleclang`

EDIT: Note, using `testrpc` would give you back error in such case. With normal network you need to use practices described in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send a transaction, your local Ethereum node will return to you a unique transaction hash. Your transaction is sent to the network (or your private node miner). Your transaction will then be chosen to be included into a block and executed, and mined by a miner.

The status of your transaction will only be know after it is mined.

To find out whether your transaction has succeeded or failed (thrown), use the procedures in [How can the transaction status from a thrown error be detected when gas can be exactly the same as the gasUsed for a successful transaction?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6007/how-can-the-transaction-status-from-a-thrown-error-be-detected-when-gas-can-be-e).

Comment: Oh, I was confused, because first I was trying it with `testrpc`, which gives you error back, so I kinda expected the same from normal net