# Why doesn't the Ethereum protocol have an indicator for a transaction that failed?

Tags: transactions, gas, out-of-gas, receipts

Why doesn't the Ethereum protocol have a clear indicator for a transaction that is reverted?

There's a heuristic [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1179/how-to-know-if-a-transaction-went-through-or-not-out-of-gas) as well as a [workaround using Geth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6007/how-can-the-transaction-status-from-a-thrown-error-be-detected-when-gas-can-be-e).  But there are probably ways that the protocol could provide a clear indicator.  For example, could a transaction receipt have a boolean property for outofgas?

What could the protocol do to provide an Out of Gas indicator, and why were none implemented?

Comment: I feel it could be used in an attack to make a node do extra work for free. Idk

Comment: Wouldn't it be a good idea to make an EIP ?

Comment: I think it's a very good idea to have that information in the transaction receipt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protocol was updated in block 4370000 (Byzantium) so that a `status` indicator has been added to receipts.

`eth.getTransactionReceipt(transactionHash)` will return a `status` field that has a value of `0` when a transaction has failed and `1` when the transaction has succeeded.

Here's an example showing the `status` field:

```
{ blockHash: '0xb1fcff633029ee18ab6482b58ff8b6e95dd7c82a954c852157152a7a6d32785e',
  blockNumber: 4370000,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 21000,
  gasUsed: 21000,
  logs: [],
  logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  root: null,
  status: 1, // **** HERE IS THE STATUS FIELD *****
  transactionHash: '0x1421a887a02301ae127bf2cd4c006116053c9dc4a255e69ea403a2d77c346cf5',
  transactionIndex: 0 }
```

(Blocks before 4370000 will have a `status` of null.)

More details [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28077/how-do-i-detect-a-failed-transaction-after-the-byzantium-fork-as-the-revert-opco).

Comment: What do you get back in the status field if you call eth.getTransactionReceipt(transactionHash) before the block associated with the Tx hash is mined?

Answer (score 3):

Most of the protocol (and more particularly the transaction receipt) is consensus critical. The amount of information it handles need to be as much as possible limited and stable. An error message doesn't really fit those requirements.

On the other hand, implementations can easily bubble up that sort of information. At least both Ethereumj and Geth do so. For an example see the "execution_error" property here:

http://api.blockcypher.com/v1/eth/main/txs/0x63b904db45e52924ff37e998a5553e2c9993bb89c0922c869fb7af8139af33ad

Comment: For Geth, are you using `debug.traceTransaction` or something else where a new answer to http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6007/how-can-the-transaction-status-from-a-thrown-error-be-detected-when-gas-can-be-e  would help?