# Checking if transaction failed over RPC

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, out-of-gas, receipts, exceptions

I call a contract over geth RPC using sendTransaction and get a transaction hash. Is there a way to verify over the geth RPC interface if this transaction failed due to a VM abort (Solidity throw statement, similar)?

The transaction receipt doesn't seem to offer any variables telling this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@eth 's answer is not accurate.

use  eth_getTransactionReceipt to get
status: QUANTITY either 1 (success) or 0 (failure)
will be more precise

reference:
https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API

```
             // Request
            curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getTransactionReceipt","params":["0xb903239f8543d04b5dc1ba6579132b143087c68db1b2168786408fcbce568238"],"id":1}'

            // Result
            {
            "id":1,
            "jsonrpc":"2.0",
            "result": {
                transactionHash: '0xb903239f8543d04b5dc1ba6579132b143087c68db1b2168786408fcbce568238',
                transactionIndex:  '0x1', // 1
                blockNumber: '0xb', // 11
                blockHash: '0xc6ef2fc5426d6ad6fd9e2a26abeab0aa2411b7ab17f30a99d3cb96aed1d1055b',
                cumulativeGasUsed: '0x33bc', // 13244
                gasUsed: '0x4dc', // 1244
                contractAddress: '0xb60e8dd61c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07233155', // or null, if none was created
                logs: [{
                    // logs as returned by getFilterLogs, etc.
                }, ...],
                logsBloom: "0x00...0", // 256 byte bloom filter
                status: '0x1'
            }
            }
```

Comment: I moved the correct answer marker. Note that the original answer was written in 2016 and the `status` field did not exist in any API by the time.

Answer (score 1):

Checking the transaction receipt for `gas == gasUsed` is a practical [heuristic](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6007/how-can-the-transaction-status-from-a-thrown-error-be-detected-when-gas-can-be-e?noredirect=1&lq=1), because the only way that the VM aborts is to [consume all gas.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2307/why-does-a-solidity-throw-consume-all-gas)

There's currently [no indicator for a transaction that ran Out of Gas,](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6144/why-doesnt-the-ethereum-protocol-have-an-indicator-for-a-transaction-that-ran-o) so nothing more precise than the heuristic is available through RPC.

Comment: How about throw statement? Does it behave the same?

Comment: Yes, the link "consume all gas" points to the question: [Why does a Solidity throw consume all gas?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2307/why-does-a-solidity-throw-consume-all-gas)