# Is it possible to make a Public Address only accept ETH/WEI from only Specified Address(es)?

Tags: addresses

... and if so what would this theoretical "rejected" transaction look like? Would the ETH/WEI be "auto-returned" back to the original Address?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.**

This question will probably be flagged as a duplicate so just a brief summary to help point you in the right direction.

**"only Specified Address(es)"**: This would be an access control list (ACL) stored in the contract. See [Are there well-solved and simple storage patterns for Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity). The contract would have admin functions to maintain the list.

**"accept ETH/WEI"**: This would be a `payable` function. The function would check the ACL, then:

1. If the `msg.sender` is on the ACL, accept, process the payment and (contract should) log an event.
2. if the `msg.sender` is not on the ACL, reject. The precise form of rejection is somewhat a matter of use-case and style. I would encourage `throw` as your default solution.

In the case of `throw`, gas is destroyed, funds are returned and any changes to the contract state are reverted. No event is emitted. If you do not `throw` (e.g. `return false;`) then you will have to unwind those matters with your code.

In terms of appearance on the chain in the `throw` case, have a look here for some insight into what happens when a transaction runs out of gas. [How to know if a transaction went through or not? (out of gas)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1179/how-to-know-if-a-transaction-went-through-or-not-out-of-gas)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice one Rob, appreciated as always! : )